# What is the name of this iteration criterion and is it implemented for Python?

Tags: python

I want to iterate a list of non-repeating numbers in "increasing resolution" (sorry, don't know the name or exactly how to call this). I will pose an example, suppose the list of numbers `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. I want to iterate this list in the following way `[1,9,5,3,7,2,4,6,8]`. The criterion is as follows: in each iteration select the list elements that are (approximately) halfway from the previously selected elements, and append those to the list. Maybe the following scheme helps:

[image]

In the zeroth iteration always select those in the extremes. Then the first iteration selects the element in the middle. In the next iteration two elements are picked, those in the middle of the previously selected. And so on. In this way, each iteration increases the resolution in some sense (thinking of this as an image for example).

How is this iteration criterion/algorithm called? Is there a function in Python that already does this for a list of numbers?

Comment: Mergesort perhaps?

Comment: I changed the terminology in your question from "sorting" to "iterating" since you seem to be describing a way to iterate a sequence in a particular order, not an algorithm for sorting a list.

Comment: @Brian each iteration: 0: pick `[1,9]` you are left with `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, 1: pick `[5]`, left `[2,3,4,6,7,8]`, 2: pick `[3,7]` left `[2,4,6,8]`, last iteration pick the remaining.

Comment: What have you tried so far? BTW, I think you should reword the title. Python, as many other languages, can iterate any way you like. It has nothing to do with the algorithm

Comment: you can use the fact that after the iteration 0 you have a either a perfect or almost perfect binary tree. Find the leaves and travel backwards

Comment: I have tried some recursive functions but not getting any close yet... That's why I put no code, sorry.

Comment: it seems a special kind of bisection method with a special order ordering rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps)) is at least similar to it, see [GIF Interlaced slow motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUq-N0TPGpU) example.

You could just code the process as you described it:

```
result = [lst[0], lst[-1]]
ranges = [(1, len(lst) - 1)]
for start, stop in ranges:
    if start < stop:
        middle = (start + stop) // 2
        result.append(lst[middle])
        ranges += (start, middle), (middle + 1, stop)
```

Result ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDdDoIwDIXv9xS93EIVB/6gkSchuyAylQTHMmaiT4@FovamSb@z09P5d7z3Li98GMduiFBCpTHDHLe4wz0esMCjEfbl7WWBRwI5gYwkeyyMEMEOz26m5FBtDMLUV9oYEWp3s8OEpKaxdZKQghVoZcS1DzDEOkSk1ntoHbD@JICqvTKF84x5ONWjbZrOkqlknsxcQZpC9hNxqHXtvXXNtLXiZ0b9JRwu@Rrh4qwQ5LIjAc3hlBA@tC5K9kX4Hl0Cf44axw8)):

```
[1, 9, 5, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Awesome, no comments!

Comment: @user171780 For a possible name/example, see the first paragraph I just added.

Comment: Yes, that video of interlaced is exactly what I was thinking of, though my application is nothing to do with an image. Thank you!

Comment: @user171780 Ha, well, your "thinking of this as an image" reminded me of that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work

```
def rareSort(inpArr):
    #first Els
    outputList = [inpArr[0],inpArr[-1]]

    
    subLists =[inpArr[1:-1]]
    while len(subLists):
        auxSubLists = []
        for el in subLists :
            if el != []:
                mid= int((len(el))/2)
                outputList.append(el[mid])
                auxSubLists += [el[0:mid], el[mid+1:]]
            else:
                pass
        subLists = auxSubLists

    return outputList



print(rareSort(inpArr))
```